# Laravel App when hosted saves images in the storage/app/ instead of storage/app/public, but saves correctly locally

Tags: php, crud, remote-access, laravel-livewire, laravel-10

community,
I have an issue with my Laravel application,
when saving images in my app, it works locally and keeps them in the correct directory, however, when I host the application to my server and try to test the application online, it now holds the images in the storage/app/ instead of the standard storage/app/public/ directory.

My storage link is in place and my function to save the image is also in place.
here is my filesystem setup

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

For example, let's look at the save user process (using livewire).

```
$data["image"] = str_replace('public/', '', $this->image->store('users'));
        $data["password"] = Hash::make("password");
        $data['status'] = $data['status'] == 1 ? User::STATUS_ACTIVE : User::STATUS_INACTIVE;

        $this->user->create($data);
        $this->resetFields();
        $this->emit("success", "User-created successfully!");
```

So the URL that is being generated afterwards looks like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/users/BYHZwuu03z4HikfcncH5hDdpjdbN7jPaQejbZ0fx.jpg
```

and to display this image,

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$user->image) }}" height="60px" width="60px" 
 class="rounded-pill">
```

When hosted online,the image doesnt display, and the link looks like this
http://{baseUrl(hidden)}/storage/users/eFJ8MLBUcREFlXpJQ5JvTQ4ZfeUYcxzB7Dc8IRy3.jpg

What could be the issue ?

Right now i don't know why the image isnt displaying,

Comment: fyi, the `width` and `height` attributes don't use units - it's integer only

Comment: Hm, you explicitly remove the `public/` folder in `str_replace('public/', '', ...`. What path gets stored in your database?

Comment: user/imagename stored in db

Answer (score -1):

Go to /root_project folder and run command :
php artisan storage:link

Hope it helps you.

Comment: There is no `artisan` command in the `public` folder

Comment: yes, I was wrong, I edited the answer

Comment: The storage link has been setup already like i mentioned, but for some reason, the image saves in a different file path on the server that's my challenge, locally it works great